# C# WPF Single Window Application with Multiple Screens

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I plan on making a single window application with multiple views. My plan is to use a main ContentControl as a container for each of the screens. I think this is fine, but am curious in best practices in handling screen changes (using MVVM).

Also, when passing parameters to new screens (UserControls) should there be a master ViewModel that holds the information?

EDIT: This is not a dual monitor/window issue. This is a single window with multiple screens.

Example Code Below:

```
public class TheMainWindow
{
//
//...other code
//
//setting the content of the ContentControl
this.ContentControlContainer.Content = new UserControlA(param);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dual monitor dual window app in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25091414/dual-monitor-dual-window-app-in-wpf)

Comment: One possible way would be to use a MVVM-Framework like for example Prism (https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/ ). It has procedures for navigation and how to move data between viewmodels.

Comment: Lets start the right way and have a TheMainWindowViewModel which is the DataContext for TheMainWindowView. In the past, I have done what you've described by using a `TabControl` and hiding the `TabHeaders` so switching between Views looks like you're changing windows. You can always go down the Prism route and start using Navigation and things like that, it all depends on how complex you want to make it.

Comment: Do your users want this?  Most users with multiple monitors probably like to control what shows up where.  That may include temporarily sending your application to the background on some monitors but not others.  There’s probably good reasons why there aren’t many single-window, multi-monitor applications.